# Looking for a transition sound clip

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects

I am creating a presentation that will be shown on a TV. I am looking for sound clip ideas that will be used for transition between sections of the presentation. For example a sound clip to transition from Introduction to History. I am thinking of an elegant, piano, smooth 15-20 sec. clip.

Comment: Try looking at some of the Enevato sites - AudioJungle might have something?

Comment: @Mark Thanks for the suggestion. I aware of those sites. I am trying to find ideas  for clips that people used in their presentations. I have a piano intro at the beginning. Should I continue to with a elegant piano theme? Or do something else to transition between sections.

Comment: Ask yourself what you are trying to achieve with the transition. Firstly - do you need music to achieve the transition? What emotional shift are you trying to communicate with the music in the transition? Start with a simple cut and work out from there. If something is missing emotionally - try different things until something starts to work. Play with gaps, beats - allow the audience a breath to transition to the new material. Remember each style of music will communicate a different emotion.